# Monomial order and prime ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $S=K[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ polynomial ring. Let $I \subseteq S$ an ideal and $<$ be a monomial order in $S$. Is it possible to describe the minimal primes of in$_<(I)$ from the minimal primes of $I$?

We can assume that $<$ is a global monomial order, and in$_<(I)$ a radical ideal.

Comment: Depends on "<"?

Comment: To be specific. Suppose $in_<(I)$ is a radical ideal. Let $P_1, \ldots, P_t$ be the minimal prime ideals of $I$. Then, $in_<(P_1), \ldots,in_<(P_t)$ are the minimal prime ideals of $in_<(i)$.
Is this true?

Comment: There are two different definitions of "monomial order". Do you assume that $<$ is a well order?

Comment: I assume that $<$ is a global monomial order. Thus, $<$ is a well order.

Comment: What is a "global monomial order"?

Comment: Is that $<$ is a total order, $1<x^{\alpha}$, and $<$ respects multiplication by monomials.

Comment: I do not know what is $x^\alpha$ (or even what is $\alpha$)? And why does it imply "well order".Total order just means linear order.

Comment: $x^{\alpha}=x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ with $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$, $\alpha \not=0$.

Comment: The  global monomial order implies well order.

Comment: Is that proved somewhere?

Comment: Yes, see Lemma 1.2.5. Book A singular introduction to commutaitva algebra.

Comment: Well, it is possible that $I$ is prime, but $in_<(I)$ is radical, but not prime, e.g. when $I$ is the ideal generated by $x_1x_2 - x_3^2$ and $<$ is a monomial order such that $x_1x_2 < x_3^2$.